# The provider provider.helm does not support data source "helm_repository"

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I am able initialize the terraform

- provider.helm: version = "~> 2.0"
- provider.kubernetes: version = "~> 2.0"
- provider.null: version = "~> 3.1"

Terraform has been successfully initialized!
using terraform Terraform v0.12.20
but when I run "terraform apply" I am getting this error "The provider provider.helm does not support data source "helm_repository"."
here is my configuration.

```
data "helm_repository" "helm-charts-all" {
  name = "helm-charts-all"
  url  = var.helm_repo
  username = ""
  password = ""
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helm repository datasource has been removed in version 2.0.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/1.2.4/docs/data-sources/repository

> Data Source: helm_repository
> Warning: This resource is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version.